# Using Amazon Machine Learning with an iOS app developed in Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, machine-learning

I am trying to develop an iOS app using AWS machine learning. I have trained a model on the cloud and it is ready to be implemented. As an input the model takes 84 numbers and outputs a binary.

I have written my app to the point which 84 numbers are produced, But i now need to integrate the machine learning.

In AppDelegate, I have:

```
import AWSCore ......
...

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
        regionType:  .euWest1,
        identityPoolId: "POOLID _HERE")
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
        region: .euWest1,
        credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    return true
}
```

In the swift file I want to use the machine learning prediction :

```
import Foundation
import AWSMachineLearning
import AWSCore
import AWSCognito.....
.....


let MachineLearning = AWSMachineLearning.default()

let modelID = "MODELID_HERE"
let getMLModelInput  = AWSMachineLearningGetMLModelInput()
getMLModelInput?.mlModelId = modelID

MachineLearning.getMLModel(getMLModelInput!).continue({ (task) -> AnyObject? in
    let getMLModelOutput = AWSMachineLearningGetMLModelOutput()
    let predictInput =  AWSMachineLearningPredictInput()
    predictInput?.predictEndpoint = getMLModelOutput?.endpointInfo?.endpointUrl
    predictInput?.mlModelId = modelID
    predictInput?.record = ["\(coefficients)":"Float"]
    let result = predictInput
    return result
})

print(result)
```

I don't know where I am making a mistake, but it is not working. Please help me with this. Also for the record input how can I input 84 float values to the model? it asks for a string input, so I am confused.

Many thanks,

Feras A.

Comment: What do you mean its not working? Are you seeing an error or is it not giving the expected output?

Comment: I get errors like : at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+}

Comment: and it is not printing a result. i expect either a 0 or 1 as an output.